# Is there any way to remove the "(index)" column from console.table() and sort the array keeping the index position?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, console.log

I'm writing a code that counts how many times a word is repeated in a text, but I'm having some problems keeping the output as expected.

```
const data = [
  { position: 28, word: "the", quantity: 10 },
  { position: 38, word: "was", quantity: 5 },
  { position: 8, word: "age", quantity: 2 },
];
const transformed = data.reduce((acc, {position, ...x}) => { acc[position] = x; return acc}, {})
console.table(transformed);
```

When printing my objects this way, I get the following output:

```
┌─────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ (index) │ word  │ quantity │
├─────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│    8    │ 'age' │    2     │
│   28    │ 'the' │    10    │
│   38    │ 'was' │    5     │
└─────────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

Then I add one more line to sort my object by quantity order

```
const data = [
  { position: 28, word: "the", quantity: 10 },
  { position: 38, word: "was", quantity: 5 },
  { position: 8, word: "age", quantity: 2 },
];
const transformed = data.reduce((acc, {position, ...x}) => { acc[position] = x; return acc}, {})
const transformedArray = Object.values(transformed).sort((a, b) => b.quantity - a.quantity);
console.table(transformedArray);
```

But that way I'm losting the positions I had before in my table

```
┌─────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ (index) │ word  │ quantity │
├─────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│    0    │ 'the' │    10    │
│    1    │ 'was' │    5     │
│    2    │ 'age' │    2     │
└─────────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

So I would like to know if there is any way to leave the table in that way:

```
┌─────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ (index) │ word  │ quantity │
├─────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│   28    │ 'the' │    10    │
│   38    │ 'was' │    5     │
│    8    │ 'age' │    2     │
└─────────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

I know I could just keep my table with the index column and also the position column, but I want to this as a last resource if there really isn't any way to fix it:

```
┌─────────┬──────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ (index) │ position │ word  │ quantity │
├─────────┼──────────┼───────┼──────────┤
│    0    │    28    │ 'the' │    10    │
│    1    │    38    │ 'was' │    5     │
│    2    │    8     │ 'age' │    2     │
└─────────┴──────────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: since `console.table` always outputs the `index` of an Array, there's no way to remove it, unless you write your own "version" of it

Comment: yeah, I was managing to make my column position become the column (index), the problem is to sort it later